# Can a full HD monitor work with nvidia geforce 6150se nforce 430 on a VGA connection?

Tags: display, graphics-card, resolution, hdmi, vga

My PC runs on a AMD Athlon Dual core processor with 2 gb RAM. The graphics card is Nvidia geforce 6150se nforce 430. I had connected my Viewsonic LCD monitor to it using a VGA cable but the monitor has stopped working and can't be repaired anymore. I plan to replace it with [Dell S2240L](http://www.dell.com/ae/business/p/dell-s2240l/pd).

My system doesn't have an HDMI port. My question is will that Full HD Dell monitor still run alright on a 1920 x 1080 resolution in my current setup or will it run on a lesser resolution? I guess it wouldn't support HD video playback.

How can I know max resolution supported by my graphics card? It's not mentioned on Nvidia website.

I assume VGA cable can handle that resolution, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically a VGA connector has no limit, but don't except a clear picture... The larger the res, the more the image will be "bloated'.

As found on wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_6_Series#GeForce_6100_and_6150_series
The maximum resolution is 2048x1536@85 Hz

So in short: Yes, you will have a screen, but it won't be HD or anything near it.